# button doesn't click in android studio

Tags: java, android, button

```
private Button mfactbutton;
private TextView mfacttext;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_fun_fact);

    Button mfactbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView mfacttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    // now we need to make out button to click
    View.OnClickListener Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String[] facts = {
                    "Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.",
                    "Ostriches can run faster than horses.",
                    "Olympic gold medals are actually made mostly of silver.",
                    "You are born with 300 bones; by the time you are an adult you will have 206.",
                    "It takes about 8 minutes for light from the Sun to reach Earth.",
                    "Some bamboo plants can grow almost a meter in just one day.",
                    "The state of Florida is bigger than England.",
                    "Some penguins can leap 2-3 meters out of the water.",
                    "On average, it takes 66 days to form a new habit.",
                    "Mammoths still walked the earth when the Great Pyramid was being built." };

            String fact = "";

            // randomly select a fact

            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(facts.length);
            fact = facts[randomNumber] + "";
        }
    };
    mfactbutton.setOnClickListener(Listener);


}
```

}

Hey everyone! i need help! my button doesn't just simply clicl!!!!! heeeeeeeeelp!i'm just trying to make a simple button that changes the textview2 with each click! at first it was working but now it started not to work.

Comment: because you are not doing anything with `mfacttext`, add `mfacttext.setText(fact)` after  this line `fact = facts[randomNumber] + "";`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Button` clicked properly but the main thing is you did not set `fact` value to `TextView`.

**#.** As you have declared `Button` and `TextView` outside `onCreate()`, no need to declare it again inside `onCreate()`.

**Use:**

```
    mfactbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mfacttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

**Instead of:**

```
    Button mfactbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView mfacttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

**#.** In `onClick()` method show `fact` value on `TextView` or show `Toast` message:

```
    // TextView
    mfacttext.setText(fact);

    // Toast
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fact: " + fact, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Here is the working code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mfactbutton;
    private TextView mfacttext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mfactbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mfacttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        // now we need to make out button to click
        View.OnClickListener Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String[] facts = {
                        "Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.",
                        "Ostriches can run faster than horses.",
                        "Olympic gold medals are actually made mostly of silver.",
                        "You are born with 300 bones; by the time you are an adult you will have 206.",
                        "It takes about 8 minutes for light from the Sun to reach Earth.",
                        "Some bamboo plants can grow almost a meter in just one day.",
                        "The state of Florida is bigger than England.",
                        "Some penguins can leap 2-3 meters out of the water.",
                        "On average, it takes 66 days to form a new habit.",
                        "Mammoths still walked the earth when the Great Pyramid was being built." };

                String fact = "";

                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(facts.length);

                fact = facts[randomNumber] + "";

                mfacttext.setText(fact);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fact: " + fact, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        mfactbutton.setOnClickListener(Listener);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you set your selected fact to your textView ? Add

```
mfacttext.setText(fact);
```

after selecting your random fact.

```
Random randomGenerator = new 
int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(facts.length);
fact = facts[randomNumber] + "";

mfacttext.setText(fact);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
  mfactbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
// Your code goes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just created a simple project. if you click on the button, it will generate random text on the textview2.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView secondTextView;
String[] Textlist = { "Hello man  ", "sonam", "tashi","i am man","hellow world"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    secondTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Button mybtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    mybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            changeTextView_two_text();

        }
    });
}

private void changeTextView_two_text() {

    Random random = new Random();
    String rand = Textlist[random.nextInt(Textlist.length)];
  //  String randomText = TextList[random.nextInt(TextList.length)];

    secondTextView.setText(rand);


}
```

}

and activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.hello.googlemap.MainActivity">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:text="click me"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="no text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/></LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps you.